# Google Cloud functions is not getting called in Dialogflow webhook

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am creating an Google Assistant action in which i have used an firebase cloud function and deployed the code to firebase cloud functions.

I have copied the webhook url and pasted it in Dialogflow console as well as enabled the Webhook call for the Default Welcome Intent.

When i run the code i am getting the error like below

[image]

Here is the cloud function code

```
const { dialogflow, Suggestions } = require("actions-on-google");

const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

app.intent("Default Welcome Intent", conv => {
  if (conv.user.last.seen) {
    conv.ask(`Welcome back to Standup Sheet`);
  } else {
    const ssml = `<speak>Welcome to Standup Sheet. I will assist you to know about your teams daily task as well the over all time taken for each project.</speak>`;
    conv.ask(ssml);
  }
  conv.ask(
    new Suggestions(["Todays entries", "Yesterday entries", "Team", "Projects"])
  );
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Logs from Firebase cloud function

```
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
{
    "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo":{
      "principalEmail":"nidhinkumar06@gmail.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata":{
        "callerIp":"2409:4072:9e:14e2:ddf4:6a38:779f:f147",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)",
        "requestAttributes":{
            "time":"2020-03-31T17:07:39.032Z",
            "auth":{}
        },
        "destinationAttributes":{}
    },
    "serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "authorizationInfo":[
        {
            "resource":"projects/standup-sheet/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
            "permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update",
            "granted":true,
            "resourceAttributes":{}
        }
    ],
    "resourceName":"projects/standup-sheet/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "request":{
        "updateMask":"description,entryPoint,timeout,availableMemoryMb,labels,environmentVariables,runtime,httpsTrigger,maxInstances,ingressSettings,vpcConnector,serviceAccountEmail,sourceUploadUrl",
        "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest",
        "function":{
            "ingressSettings":"ALLOW_ALL",
            "httpsTrigger":{},
            "serviceAccountEmail":"standup-sheet@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
            "entryPoint":"dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
            "labels":{
                "deployment-tool":"console-cloud"
            },
            "sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-6a75406d-6f0b-41ee-aeb5-e264da4377bc/22bd91a1-48f6-4daa-981a-e76122332e1c.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-1064672465268@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1585676258&Signature=QqhcwyJXqap%2BWXvJ6Xu2hqINSaw5uNAdRadrfIFAyXEd%2F5DTkKeEmUBjlOWrcHOrbdR6lXzgLeiIERBGHud4sZ5FQSWHOJ6HBJ3OHTI0PhEuUPBhEyuGSn%2FqI3kav9QHf5tETNw2L1DXvUw0oU%2BcD6V0MSwC35D4pGCUPoqvxW38W0q7Yz0bXm26Wnlk3HwTm%2FjP2OwbQEH5Ae5mntn%2BdQHH4n2RFjXyg2JIIDVBe1f1rOzSh0vDL4Eg6Fc9n7HMfOSfJ04RoqnAj1gUUZo38uQSVfIfjVjSqEjbR%2BGvF8E2lw5CUX%2FS8BKeqq4hvSpTUmvdmGJe0qGt8ohBq524Lw%3D%3D",
            "timeout":"60s",
            "availableMemoryMb":256,
            "name":"projects/standup-sheet/locations/us-central1/functions/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
            "runtime":"nodejs8"
        }
    },
    "resourceLocation":{
        "currentLocations":["us-central1"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include any output from the Firebase Cloud Function Logs?

Comment: @Prisoner Updated the question that's the only log which gets printed added a log in the Default Welcome Intent but it doesn't show

Comment: That looks like an audit log for when you updated your function. There should be something if you go to the project on the Firebase Console, select "Functions" on the left, and then "Logs" at the top.

Comment: @Prisoner only this audit logs are available no other logs
https://imgur.com/IkEaXfY

Comment: What is the url you pasted into Dialogflow?

Comment: @NickFelker The URL which is available in the cloud functions something like this
https://us-central1-standup-sheet.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the code is working now done below steps to make it work. If anyone faces this kind of issue pls check the below steps.

**Root cause #1**

In Dialogflow console i have removed all the default response in the Default Welcome Intent that causes the above error. So i added a default response and tested the action which works fine. But the response from the cloud function was not shown.

**Root cause #2**

Tried to use the inline editor in Dialogflow and check whether that function is getting called or not. Tried to enable the inline editor but it doesn't enable stating **Google Cloud needs to be provisioned, pls refresh the page**. Looked the GCP console and compared other actions which i have created every action has storage but this action doesn't so i have created storage in Firebase after enabling the Storage Inline editor was enabled (Raised a Query in Dialogflow to confirm whether it is because of Storage does the inline editor is not opened).

**Solution 1**

Once the inline editor is opened pasted the above code and the package.json file and deployed the code and tested it works as expected

**Solution 2**

Tried to deploy the same code from my machine and enabled **Webhook** instead of the inline editor and tested the action works as expected

**Solution 3**

Changed the exports **dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment** name to **fulfillment** and deployed the code and tested it doesn't work so compared both the functions and found that the **fulfillment** function doesn't have the permission like the below image

[image]

If you notice in the above image there is a role named **allUsers** whereas in the **fulfillment** function it doesn't have the allUsers role

[image]

As well as if you look at the functions dashboard(dialogflowFirebasefulfillment) you can notice the difference

[image]

fulfillment(dashboard)

[image]

To enable the permission for it click on the info panel and click **Add Members** and add **allUsers** like below

[image]

Once it is done add the role for allUsers by clicking the **Cloud Functions** and **Cloud Functions Invoker** and click save.

[image]

Now you can see the updated dashboard like below

[image]

Now if you test the action it will call the cloud function.